# How to build QCharts module using Visual Studio (Windows 64bit)?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, build, module, 64-bit

I can't build QCharts module using Visual Studio on Windows 64bit. A link error occurs:

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

Steps:

- Download from: [qtcharts-opensource-src-5.7.0-rc.zip](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0-rc/submodules/qtcharts-opensource-src-5.7.0-rc.zip)
- Setting environment on prompt (qtenv2.bat and vcvarsall.bat)
- execute qmake and nmake on QCharts directory

How to build with platform flag using qmake and nmake on Windows 64bit?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in this question to make it useful to anyone, including yourself. Are you building your copy of Qt? Imagine we start with decompressed Qt source folder and a build folder, then we open a command prompt - what exact steps do you take to build Qt?

Comment: You're using 32-bit Qt with a 64 bit compiler, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I ran vcvarsall.bat with x64 parameter on prompt (step 2) and it works.